# Is it permissible for a Noahide to become transgender?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, noachide-laws, noahidism

In Judaism, there seem to be [several prohibitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transgender_people_and_religion#Orthodox_Judaism) regarding transgenderism:

> The removal of genital organs is forbidden on the basis of the prohibition against "anything which is mauled, crushed, torn or cut" (Leviticus 22:24). A further prohibition in Deuteronomy 22:5 proscribes not only cross-dressing but any action uniquely identified with the opposite sex, and this would also apply to an operation to transform sexual characteristics.

Now, one of the Noahide commandment categories forbids engagement in sexual immorality. Does trying to change one's sex fall under this or would it be permissible for a Noahide to become transgender? Would things like this also apply to Noahidism?

Also, "by changing one's sex", I mean undergoing things such as hormone replacement therapy, genital surgical removal in cases of male-to-female transgender people (more generally, gender reassignment surgery), and potentially in the future, even things like uterus transplants.

Comment: @RabbiKaii In Judaism, transgenderism is generally not allowed AFAIK. I was wondering if for Noahides, there is such a prohibition due to the category of sexual immorality and transgender or transexuality is changing one's sex to a different one. So things like genital removal, hormone therapy, possibly even if one is going from male to female to have uterus transplants in the not too distant future, etc.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Oh ok, I will modify it then

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will point out that the source you brought doesn't mention sexual immorality. It will still be useful to find a source for that. It seems likely the laws of sexual morality could be relevant, so if you are just asking if they are, that might need to be its own question first

Comment: @Kirk does that mean one should rather die than cross dress? See Igros Moshe O.C. IV 75:3

Comment: Okay but that doesn’t exclude it from generally being under the umbrella of sexual licentiousness forbidden to Bnei noach @RabbiKaii